# I am trying to add a seperate switch to an existing 3 way circuit

Tags: switch

I currently have a 3-way circuit (2 switches) that control 4 recessed lights and the light over the kitchen island.  I would like to be able to "split" the recessed lights from the island lights.  Meaning I would like an additional switch to turn on / off the island light separately from the recessed lights.  can that be done with a wireless switch or any products like the remote control unit on a ceiling fan? Any other ideas that do not require cabling/rewiring will all be appreciated

Comment: Harp:  I know for us experienced in this, it should be obvious to turn off the circuit first, but newbies may not think of that.   Please edit your post to include "be sure to turn off the breaker for that circuit before pulling out the switches. "

Comment: Can you post photos of insides of the boxes involved please, with the breaker for the circuit off of course?

Comment: We'll need photos of what is going on inside each and every involved switch box. We'll need to see the switches pulled out (but NOT disconnected!) so we can see the wires inside the box and how they group into cables. Move wires around a bit if you have to, to make the pics more clear. TURN OFF THE BREAKER FIRST!

Comment: The problem with a wireless remote is that the receiver needs power.  You won't have constant power unless the switch is on and all the other lights are on.  Chances are very slim of this working without running at least one new wire.